# What is the interjection often used in front of "I like that"?

Tags: interjections

I often heard an interjection   used in front of "I like that", when someone wants to say they like something which  might be inappropriate or offend some others.  It sounds like "woah", but I doubt it is.  What is it? Thanks.

Comment: Often "Oh", which could sound like "woah". Other ones that don't sound like "woah" are "Yes", "Yeah" and "Oh yes". However I have no references so this is a comment not an answer. Different people use different ones at different times as well.

Comment: If they know it might offend or is inappropriate but they wish to express their liking regardless, they might say, “Sorry, but I like that.”

Comment: Woah seems possible. Why doubt it?  It's used to express surprise, interest, or alarm, or to command attention.